# Is it faster to write Images into a new file or to copy them?

Tags: java, image, performance, io, copy

I'm currently developping a software which uses images. The soft loads them from the HD and uses them but it doesn't modify them.

Consequently, I have some Images instanciated into the RAM.
In a particular case, I have to write those pictures on the hard drive (but in a different directory than their original location).

Actually, I do not know what is the most efficient way to do this. Is it faster to copy a file from one folder to another one (with `Files.copy()`) or should I write my RAM-loaded pictures into a new file (using a `BufferedWriter` for exemple)?

In my opinion, writing a new file from loaded pictures could be faster because it doesn't have to read a file on the HD. However, I'm not sure about it and I don't know what is the real process behind `Files.copy()`.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: It's definitely faster to copy the file. Not to mention simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd bet that copying is usually faster.

- If you're lucky, the image is buffered by the OS and you don't really access the disk for reading it, so the advantage of writing from memory vanishes.
- Any sane image format (and I don't mean BMP) is compressed and an image in memory is not (you want to work with it, right?). And compression is a rather slow operation.

That all said, only a measurement can tell you for sure.

---

I used a JPG for my benchmark, as it's a computationally expensive format.

```
private void go() throws Exception {
    final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(src);
    for (int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
        write(image);
        copy();
    }
}

private void write(BufferedImage image) throws Exception {
    final long start = System.nanoTime();
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", dst);
    final long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.format("write %15.6f\n", 1e-9 * (end-start));
}

private void copy() throws Exception {
    final long start = System.nanoTime();
    Files.copy(src.toPath(), dst.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    final long end = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.format("copy  %15.6f\n", 1e-9 * (end-start));
}
```

The results are as follows

```
write        0.200160
copy         0.001850
write        0.200056
copy         0.001886
```

So copying wins by two order of magnitude. Whoever claims that using JPG is unfair should do their own tests.

Comment: Your answer makes sense for me. I'm gonna try both solutions to evaluate which one is the most efficient. But your suggestion about compression makes me think you're probably right.

Comment: I did a test and write from memory was 50% faster than do a file copy, so this is not the right answer.

Comment: @chokdee Get a slower CPU and/or a faster disk and then it is. What format did you use? It wasn't JPG, right?

Comment: @maaartinus so seems to be you will not believe, do your own test before wrting wrong answers or believe whatever you want. btw: it was a jpeg file and I've used a SDD, any other´questions?

Comment: @chokdee For me, copying wins hands down, see my update. SSD, i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz, 3MB JPG.

Comment: 1) you don't have to run both test together, otherwise you have a dependency with the IO Caches
2) You have to use a bufferedwriter with a large amount of initial data, you will see other results...

Answer (score 0):

It is faster to store the RAM loaded Image to the file system because you don't have to read it again from the filesystem.

Comment: It will never be faster to read from a file than to read from memory!